# Implementing password recovery if users have no email account

Tags: security, passwords, change-password

Ok, so I've inherited an open-source project with user logins that are a simple username/password combo. Unfortunately, if someone forgets their password, we don't have a password recovery option. I'm hoping to fix that now, but not sure how to do it securely, given that we don't have any other identifying characteristics. User accounts have no recovery email, no "secret questions," etc.

A user account consists only of 1) username, 2) encrypted password, 3) List of document ids which the user has editor access (but this is publicly visible by viewing the user's public page)

Now that I have access to the project, I will be implementing OAuth or similar, but as for old accounts with forgotten passwords that have since been logged out, is there any right way to ID my users so they can do a password reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no great way of doing this.  You just don't have the information; not even enough to contact users.  Until a user has supplied their username and password, you can't communicate with them.

You'll need to add a check that runs every time a user authenticates, which checks if they've set recovery data (email or whatever you decide on).  From there you have a variety of options, depending on how important you find the recovery data.  In order of severity, you could:

1. Disallow use of the site until they have added and verified
   recovery data.  Essentially, full authentication fails if recovery
   data is not set.
2. Prompt them to add recovery data, but allow them to skip it.
3. Notify them that the ability to set recovery data has been added, but take no further action.

If you are dramatically changing login, you'll need to support the legacy method as well until such time as you want to abandon users who haven't made the switch.